# Why did Annie do this at the end of Hereditary?

Tags: plot-explanation, hereditary

At the end of the movie *Hereditary (2018)*, leviating, Annie beheads herself with a piano wire in front of Peter.

Why did she behead herself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annie is possessed by Paimon. For this reason, She chops her own head off. The decapitations were needed  for the ritual.

1. Charlie’s death was designed by the cult:

> Charlie sticks her head out of the window in an attempt to ease her
>   breathing, and is decapitated by a wooden post. The post bears the
>   same symbol that is on the necklace Annie's mother gave her (and
>   continues to crop up throughout the film). An internet search
>   identifies it as the 'Seal of Paimon' from the real-life 'spell book'
>   The Lesser Key of Solomon.

[Digitalspy](https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a858796/hereditary-explained-plot-ending/)

2. Ellen's head is removed from her body by the cult members who dig up her grave.

> Ari Aster: The cult of "Paimonists" dug her up and put her there (as
>   per grandma's instructions).

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/8rbjj7/hi_im_ari_aster_writerdirector_of_hereditary_ama/)

3. Annie beheaded herself, influenced by Paimon.

In the movie, Peter is told that the trinity has been destroyed and that Paimon now reigns.

> Ari Aster: Well, Joan does mention that the cult has "rejected the
>   Holy Trinity" at the end, so that's there.

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/8rbjj7/hi_im_ari_aster_writerdirector_of_hereditary_ama/)

The decapitated bodies, who have been positioned into a worshipful position (They're all arranged in a triangle), represent an "Unholy Trinity": the Maiden, the Mother, and the Crone (the Triple Goddess of certain forms of Neopaganism)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_Goddess_(Neopaganism))

[image: Paimon]

In the illustration of the book, Paimon has three heads.